# Postgres ltree multiple paths

Tags: postgresql, ltree

Okay, so I have a table with ltree on a column called path. I want to select multiple paths, but I don't want to have a ton of OR statements. Is that possible or is this the best way to do it?

Paths:

- 'schools.myschool.*'
- 'companies.about.*'
- 'testing.information.content.*'

Query:

`SELECT content, path FROM threads WHERE path ~ 'schools.myschool.*' OR path ~ 'companies.about.*' OR path ~ 'testing.information.content.*`

Comment: If you want `.` as separator, you should use `\.` instead of `.`, and if the suffix should be separated by a dot too, you should express that with `\..*` or `\..+`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'schools.myschool.*' ~ any(array[
    'schools.myschool.*', 'companies.about.*', 'testing.information.content.*'
]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: I like this solution, but just for clarification, I think the OP means `.*` as a wildcard. Your expression should match `schools.myschool.yourclass` for instance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can join the regular expressions into one with the or-operator `|`, and by separating the common suffix:

```
SELECT content, path FROM threads 
WHERE path ~ '(schools.myschool|companies.about|testing.information.content).*'
```